# Hide columns in jqgrid based on user role.

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

If I try something like

```
$("#list").hideCol("ColumnName")
```

This will happen only after the grid load is complete. I want more like how hidden: true in column model works.

Comment: Then you can use `hidden: true` property of `colModel` for the specified users. Where you see the problem? You don't explained the scenario, which you use. Which `datatype` you use? Where you get the information about the user role? **When** you get the information about the user role? Do you know the information during creating the grid?... Which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriggo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use?

Comment: I am sorry. My scenario is ColModel gets loaded dynamically from an xml. So thats out of the option and I am using free jqgrid, latest. I can check the user role by an ajax call. Is there a way to hide or show columns before load complete event?

Comment: Then you can modify `colModel` and include `hidden: true` in the corresponding column if the user not in the role. If you creates the grid *after* the modification you will have no problems.

Comment: Entire column model comes as xml for me, I cannot change or modify the colModel, I use multiple xmls with single jqgrid,

Comment: Everything is dynamic, from jqgrid id to every property is dynamic.

Comment: You don't need to modify XML, but you have array of items which you use as parameter of `colModel`. You can modify the items of the array without any problem or side effect. You should just most more code and more description in the text of your question.

Comment: Yes. Assume I have the colModel in 'ColumnModel' parameter, before creating jqgrid like ... $("#" + me.grid.gridId).jqGrid({........... I will do this operation. Thanks This should work.